# error con arrayList en java

Tags: java, array, arraylist, recursión

estoy haciendo una implementaciòn del problema de la n-reinas en java, la idea es tener un arrayList que guarde arreglos y a su vez cada arreglo sea una soluciòn distinta, pero cuando reviso el arrayList los arreglos estan llenos de puros 7.

el codigo es este:

```
   public static void queens(int[] tablero, int x,ArrayList soluciones) {
    int n = tablero.length; 
    if (x >= n) // verifica que todas las reinas esten puestas
        if (esValido(tablero)){ // metodo que mira si las reinas estan bien puestas
            soluciones.add(tablero); // se añade el tablero al arreglo que guarda las soluciones
            return;
        }
        else {
            return;
        } 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { // for para ir poniendo las reinas  
        tablero[x] = i; // coloca la reina en la fila i columna x 
        queens(tablero, x + 1,soluciones); 
    }
}
```

el metodo esValido es este:

```
   public static boolean esValido(int[] tablero) {
    int n = tablero.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (tablero[i] < 0 || tablero[i] >= n) 
            return false;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            if (i != j) {
                if (tablero[i] == tablero[j])
                    return false;
                if (i - j == Math.abs(tablero[i] - tablero[j]))
                    return false;
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que cheques bien su "if" en cada uno de los ciclos, es por ello que algunas no se cumplen y te pasan el mismo valor. Saludos